# Is it possible to do something like Placeholder text color should be combination of two colors in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

`<Entry PlaceHolder="Enter Username*" placeholdercolor="Black" Text={binding Username}/>`

Here,The Username has to be in Black color and astrick(*)has to be in red color.Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such functionality available out-of-the-box for `Entry` with current `Xamarin.Forms` version. Here is [the official `Entry` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#setting-placeholder-text).

An easy workaround could be to move the placeholder to a separate label. In last version of `Xamarin.Forms` a `FormattedText` property was introduced on a `Label`. So you could split the text to several chunks while customising it:

```
<Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Red Bold, " TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Span Text="default, " Style="{DynamicResource BodyStyle}">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
            <Span Text="italic small." FontAttributes="Italic" FontSize="Small" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text).